Simple Sendable issue with Swift6
I want to create a class that conforms to sendable that holds an array of Ints. However I get the following  error:
Stored property '_counters' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'Manager' is mutable
Could you point me to how to resolve this. thanks
@Observable final class Manager:Sendable{
    
    var hasContent:Bool{
        return counters.count > 0
    }
    private var counters:[Int] = []
    
    func lastNumber()->Int?{
        return counters.count == 0 ? nil : counters.last
    }
    
    func addCounter(){
        let number = Int.random(in: 1...50 )
        counters.append(number)
    }
}


Idiomatically !counters.isEmpty is preferable to counters.count > 0. Also lastNumber can simply return counters.last since that returns an optional

Why should an observable class be sendable?

"Could you point me to how to resolve this". The short (but not useful) answer is to remove the counters property. You can also decorate the class as @MainActor, but Joakim's question is a good one. Why are you doing this?

if you mark Manager as Observable you can pass it to multiple views, and the views will respond to only the parts they use and redraw when those values change. In that way the Manager class can be quite coherent,  and I dont need to parcel off its parts separately. I thought that was the whole power of @ Observable. In this way, for example, I can pass it down to the children as an environment object.

Yes that is correct but how does Sendable come into the picture, what you have mentioned will all happen on the main actor without crossing any actor boundaries? Have you perhaps misunderstood the purpose of the Sendable protocol?

You need a "global actor"

As others have said in the comments, this is a very unusual thing to do. Rather than sending the whole Manager to another concurrency context, consider sending just the data you need, as a value type. For example, in this case you should just send over the counters as a simple [Int].
Suppose you want to send a Manager from a main actor isolated context to a non-isolated context by passing it to a non-isolated function doSomething.
func doSomething(_ x: Manager) async { ... }

@MainActor
func caller(_ manager: Manager) async {
    await doSomething(manager)
}

You should change doSomething to take a [Int] instead,
func doSomething(_ x: [Int]) async { ... }

@MainActor
func caller(_ manager: Manager) async {
    await doSomething(manager.counters)
}

If the other concurrency context needs to modify the data, you can design it so that it sends back the changes too. e.g. doSomething could return a [Int] indicating what the new counters should be.
func doSomething(_ x: [Int]) async -> [Int] { ... }

@MainActor
func caller(_ manager: Manager) async {
    manager.counters = await doSomething(manager.counters)
}

doSomething could also return an AsyncStream/AsyncChannel that caller can consume. As the work progresses, doSomething would send elements down the stream. The UI can show the current state of a long-running operation this way.
If you really want to send a reference type to another concurrency context, send an actor. Then, after whatever needs to be done is done, update your @Observable class with the state of the actor.
func doSomething(_ x: ActorManager) async {  }

@MainActor
func caller(_ manager: Manager) async {
    let actorManager = ActorManager(counters: manager.counters)
    await doSomething(actorManager)
    manager.counters = await actorManager.counters
}

actor ActorManager {
    var counters: [Int]
    init(counters: [Int]) {
        self.counters = counters
    }
}


Finally, it is not impossible for a @Observable class to conform to Sendable, if you protect counters with a Mutex plus some hacking around,
import Synchronization

@Observable
final class SendableManager: Sendable {
    
    var hasContent: Bool {
        counters.withLock {
            access(keyPath: \.dummy)
            return !$0.isEmpty
        }
    }
    
    private let counters = Mutex([Int]())
    
    private let dummy: () = ()
    
    func lastNumber() -> Int? {
        counters.withLock {
            access(keyPath: \.dummy)
            return $0.last
        }
    }
    
    func addCounter() {
        counters.withLock { counters in
            withMutation(keyPath: \.dummy) {
                let number = Int.random(in: 1...50 )
                counters.append(number)
            }
        }
    }
}

Note that there is a dummy property. This is used to record reads and writes to the counter property - the counters property cannot be directly passed to observation-related methods like access and withMutation because it is not Copyable.

I saw a Sendable manager in a sample @Observable class TrailDataManager: @unchecked Sendable  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/acceleratingappinteractionswithappintents maybe its possible because all the data is lets.
